# How to read RSS feed from FIFA/ESPN?

Tags: android, xml, rss

I have previously worked with [Cric Info RSS](http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml) in my android application. I have the know-how of reading the RSS feed from the tags (Link, Description, Title) using XmlPullParser.

However, Now that I want to integrate [FIFA RSS](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/news/rss.xml) or [ESPN RSS](http://www.espnfc.com/fifa-world-cup/4/rss) for football news in my application, I see no tags that I can use to filter the required data.

How can I fetch data from these resources that are offering raw XML? 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: it is not clear what is a problem for you to fetch raw rss.

Comment: Both Fifa and ESPN RSS feeds are providing raw data. There are no tags using which I will filter the data that I need. 
My Question is, how can I filter the data i.e. title, description, timestamp, url etc from the given raw data.   @Vladyslav Matviienko

Answer (score 2):

I am getting a response with the tags from the Fifa's RSS url. Maybe the browser is parsing it for you and you don't get to see them?
Run this curl request on your terminal/console and check the response

```
curl -v \
-H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1.0, es-419;q=0.9, en;q=0.8" \
-H "User-Agent: Russia2018/2.1 (com.looping.gameon; build:7; iOS 11.3.0) Alamofire/4.7.0" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
"http://es.fifa.com/worldcup/news/rss.xml"
```

I am getting back something like:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><channel><title><![CDATA[FIFA.com - Copa Mundial de la FIFA Rusia 2018 - Noticias]]></title><link>http://es.fifa.com/index.html</link><language>es</language><copyright>Copyright© 1994 - 2018 FIFA. Reservados todos los derechos</copyright><description>Visite FIFA.com para acceder a todas las noticias, entrevistas y el gran debate del fútbol mundial. </description><pubDate>Mon, 23 Apr 2018 16:28:00 GMT</pubDate><lastBuildDate>Fri, 27 Apr 2018 20:13:13 GMT</lastBuildDate><category>FIFA.com</category><image><title><![CDATA[FIFA.com - Copa Mundial de la FIFA Rusia 2018 - Noticias]]></title><url>//img.fifa.com/imgml/rssheader.gif</url><link>http://es.fifa.com/index.html</link><width>139</width><height>28</height><description>rssFifa</description></image><atom:link href="http://es.fifa.com/worldcup/news/rss.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" /><item><guid isPermaLink="false">1524859338044</guid><title><![CDATA[La Gira del Trofeo llega a Japón]]></title><link>http://es.fifa.com/worldcup/news/y=2018/m=4/news=la-gira-del-trofeo-llega-a-japon-2945044.html</link><description>&lt;p&gt;El avión que ha llevado el trofeo por todo el planeta despegó para realizar su penúltimo vuelo el 27 de abril, desde la RP China, para recalar en Tokio. Japón es el último país que visitará en la fase global.&lt;/p&gt;
```

Fri, 27 Apr 2018 11:27:00 GMT....

Comment: I've run it in Postman and it gives me the same result as you. 
However I can't use it with XmlPullParser, unable to parse the data. but I'll lool into it.
Thanks for the help.